# My angular observables are flipped over several times

Tags: angular, observable

Bonjour,

I'm retrieving data from an API.
The retrieved data are displayed on 6 counters and some of these data are to be displayed on 3 graphs on 3 identical tabs.
I use a service because all my components are at the root of my application. So I don't have any parent/child.

Here is my code :

The service:

```
  data = [];
  private paramSource = new BehaviorSubject(this.data);
  public sharedData$: Observable<any> = this.paramSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private apiClient: ApiClientService) {
  }

  getProducts() {
    return this.apiClient.get(this.apiUrl);
  }

  setData(data) {
    this.paramSource.next(data);
  }
```

The component that displays graphics :

```
export class GraphicComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() graphicData: any = [];
  chartOptions: {};

  Highcharts = Highcharts;

  constructor(public dataMlsService: DataMlsService) {
    dataMlsService.sharedData$.subscribe(data => {
      this.graphicData = data;
      console.log(this.graphicData);
    });
  }
  setChar(graphicData) {
    this.chartOptions = {
      chart: {
        type: 'spline'
      },
      title: false,
      xAxis: {},
      yAxis: {
        title: false,
      },
      legend: false,
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      series: graphicData,
    };
    // console.log(this.graphicData);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
*    this.setChar(this.graphicData);
  }
}
```

And here's a component which is the tab:

```
export class LocationComponent implements OnInit {

  // Réaliser côté back la fonction pour les biens en baisse de prix
  newCurrentLeases: any[];
  newLeases: any[];
  newReservedGoods: any[];
  goodsHired: any[];
  archivedLeasedGoods: any[];
  cheaperGoodsRented: any[];

  constructor(public dataMlsService: DataMlsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataMlsService.getProducts().subscribe((data) => {
      this.newCurrentLeases = data['newCurrentLeases'];
      this.newLeases = data['newLeases'];
      this.newReservedGoods = data['newReservedGoods'];
      this.goodsHired = data['goodsHired'];
      this.archivedLeasedGoods = data['archivedLeasedGoods'];
      this.cheaperGoodsRented = data['cheaperGoodsRented'];
      this.dataMlsService.setData(data);
    });
  }
}
```

The Html part:

```
  <div class="container-graphic">
      <app-graphic [status]="statusChangementPrix" [graphicData]="cheaperGoodsRented"></app-graphic>
  </div>
```

My concern is that I receive data several times when I would like to retrieve the observable once. The observables are returned 3 times because I have 3 graphs.

Here is the console when I go to a tab :

```
graphic.component.ts:21 []
graphic.component.ts:21 []
graphic.component.ts:21 {newCurrentLeases: Array(71), newGoodsInProgress: Array(728), newCompromise: Array(0), newLeases: Array(0), newVacancy: Array(2), …}
graphic.component.ts:21 {newCurrentLeases: Array(71), newGoodsInProgress: Array(728), newCompromise: Array(0), newLeases: Array(0), newVacancy: Array(2), …}
graphic.component.ts:21 {newCurrentLeases: Array(71), newGoodsInProgress: Array(728), newCompromise: Array(0), newLeases: Array(0), newVacancy: Array(2), …}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything works as expected:)
You have 3 components and each component makes a call to api:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.dataMlsService.getProducts().subscribe((data) => {
      this.newCurrentLeases = data['newCurrentLeases'];
      this.newLeases = data['newLeases'];
      this.newReservedGoods = data['newReservedGoods'];
      this.goodsHired = data['goodsHired'];
      this.archivedLeasedGoods = data['archivedLeasedGoods'];
      this.cheaperGoodsRented = data['cheaperGoodsRented'];
      this.dataMlsService.setData(data);
    });
  }
```

You have to move it on upper level and pass data to your components with `@Input()` https://angular.io/api/core/Input

Comment: I think you're right. I had created a special component for the graphic but I'm going to drop it...

Answer (score 1):

I would use pipe with filter (I guess u dont need that data===[]) and take(1) so you receive exactly one piece for subscribe method.

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.dataMlsService.getProducts()
          .pipe(
            filter(data=>data!==[]),
            take(1))
          .subscribe((data) => {
//    here we recieve only filled data once
        });
      }
```

Also don't forget about importing filter,take from 'rxjs/operators'

Comment: Ah, that's not bad, what you're offering me. On the other hand my IDE tells me that I can't do .subcribe.

Comment: Yeee i've edited it :) Typo, unnecessary ) after data.

Comment: TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction{}>'.

Comment: I thought getProducts() returns Observable. Now I believe it's Subscription. I think that getProducts should return Observable and let the caller of method decide what to do with it.